# Number of pairs of integers $(a,b)$ with $a^2+b^2=n$ for a constant $n$

Tags: number-theory

Is there a more general formula for the number of pairs of nonnegative integers $(a,b)$ with $a^2+b^2=n$ for arbitrary $n$?

Comment: did you search in [the internet](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html)

Comment: @Elaqqad: love that "the"!